# How to Find total length in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
def totaal_length(s1,s2):
    """ (str,str)->int
          return the doubled difference of the lengths of s1 and s2.

          >>>total_length('yes','no')
          2
          """
```

what is return ?

Comment: your question is vague. if your variable `x` is a string use `print(len(x))`. if it's an array of strings use `print(len(x[i]))` for `i`th element.

Answer (score 0):

You can get two argument length, mutlitply by 2 and subtract:

```
def total_length(s1,s2):
  return abs((len(s1)*2)-(len(s2)*2))
```

Comment: @Chillie many thanks man for the note, extremely helpful if first length is smaller than the other